Internal DNS Architecture for Active Directory and non-Active Directory clients with overlapping IP range
My organization is moving from one Active Directory domain that we did not own, to a new AD domain that we are the domain admins for. We have offices all over the continental US. Those offices have their own IT staff that operates with significance autonomy from our HQ. Each office has varying degrees of non-Active Directory joined systems. The situation that I'm looking to get advice on is this: The Active Directory Integrated DNS zone must be authoritative for the AD domain, for the forward lookup zone and the corresponding reverse lookup zones. We will call the forward lookup domain "Directory.Company.com". We have a separate DNS server/zone for any non-AD clients that get a DNS name. We will call this one "Linux.Company.com". Some clients for both Directory.Company.com and Linux.Company.com will be part of the same IP range. But both DNS servers will want to be authoritative for the reverse lookup zone.
I am trying to determine a best practice or recommended architecture for handling this situation. One possible option we are exploring is that we have a DNS server that resides in our internal network. All clients would use this as their configured DNS server. This server would handle recursive lookups for our Active Directory, Non-AD DNS, and internet related queries. Additionally, it would be authorized (somehow) to dynamically create, update and delete records (forward and reverse) in the AD and non-AD DNS zones.
A second possibility is to separate the AD and non-AD clients into IP ranges that do not overlap. However, this would take significant work for our network team.
If anyone can refer me to best practices on this, that'd be great. I would like to hear what other organizations have done in a similar situation as well. Thanks in advance.

best practice or recommended architecture Most Active Directory implementations don't need or use reverse lookup DNS zones. That's one option.

Why would AD not need or use reverse lookup? I know reverse lookups probably are not used as often as forward lookups, but we certainly use reverse lookups.

You or your applications may need it. Active Directory simply doesn't use it.


The Active Directory Integrated DNS zone must be authoritative for the AD domain, for the forward lookup zone and the corresponding reverse lookup zones

Active Directory has no such requirement for reverse lookup zones – neither that they be AD-integrated nor that they exist at all. Reverse lookups are not used as part of any AD operations (specifically not even Kerberos); domain member machines will try to send an update for the reverse zone but will function the same way regardless of the result.
There is also no requirement (neither in AD nor in general) that the same server should host forward and reverse zones. As far as DNS is concerned, they are completely independent entities; a DNS server hosting a forward zone does not automatically "want" to become authoritative for the respective reverse zone (if it were even possible for it to determine one1), and an AD member host will always send separate DNS updates for both the forward and reverse records.
(1 There is also no requirement for a 1:1 correspondence of forward and reverse zones.)
This means that if you want to have a reverse zone for your network, it does not matter where you host it. You can host it on AD DCs and have Linux machines update it, or you can host it on Linux BIND9 and have Windows machines update it (both AD and BIND9 implement the same update protocol); it will work the same way.

One possible option we are exploring is that we have a DNS server that resides in our internal network. All clients would use this as their configured DNS server. This server would handle recursive lookups for our Active Directory, Non-AD DNS, and internet related queries. Additionally, it would be authorized (somehow) to dynamically create, update and delete records (forward and reverse) in the AD and non-AD DNS zones.

The server used by clients for queries is not necessarily the server used for updates. When a client is about to perform a dynamic DNS update, it will always query the 'master' server indicated in the zone's SOA record – it will not just blindly send the update to its DNS resolver.
This specifically allows the resolver to be read-only without any update capabilities; as long as the clients are able to look up SOA for their AD forward zone they'll directly send the updates to an AD domain controller regardless.
(As a practical example, we use Unbound – a read-only resolver – as our network-wide DNS server, and there isn't a single machine that has AD DCs specified as nameservers, but they all know to send dynamic updates to dc01 according to the zone's DNS SOA record.)
